# How to create an EOS account using eosjs without existing account and its private key

Tags: smartcontracts, cryptocurrency, eos

I have a question about EOS, eosio and eosjs.

I want to create an EOS account using frontend website that I developed.
I I recognize that creating an account needs existing account, and needs its private key.
But, I think putting a private key on frontend website is so danger.

Let me know how to create account without existing account and its private key.

Answer (score 0):

it cannot be done.  the system is just not designed to allow that to happen.  in part it's because someone needs to pay for the new account.  this is a big problem for retail applications with the potential to grow since the app developer would have to pay for the accounts